# Text Field is invisible in Android Studio 2.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, textfield

I don't know if this is a feature of Android Studio 2.2.1 or not, but I was following thenewboston's android tutorials and his text fields appear as a single line that shows the user where to input text.

In my android studio, the line is invisible. The text field is still there, and I can edit its properties, but the field itself is invisible till I run it on the emulator(Android 5.1/Google API). Is this a rendering problem, or is this normal? This is causing me a huge problem as I can't see exactly where I've placed the text fields in text view.

Design view : 
[image: Text Field line Missing]

Emulator:
[image: Text Field line Present]

If it is normal, how can I force Android Studio to display a line to indicate a text field as it does in the emulator?

Here's the text for activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.somu.tnbtut11.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:text="Sign In"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="27dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:width="250dp"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="false" />

<TextView
    android:text="Password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="eMail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3" />

<Button
    android:text="Log In"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
    android:width="250dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Note**: Changing app theme doesn't make the text fields appear!
[image: App Theme Light, as suggested by answer]

Comment: show your xml file .

Comment: there is not any problem in xml :)

Answer (score 2):

> This is normal. You can change app theme Light and you will see line

Comment: Doesn't work.. Changed app theme to Material.Light. This is the output: http://imgur.com/a/3m4AF

Comment: This doesn't really explain why the theme is not showing the textboxes.

Comment: you change theme Holo Dark

Comment: @EmreAslan The lines appear for Holo Theme, but NOT for any other theme. Why doesn't it appear for every theme?

Comment: please you try this code in EditText xml . <requestFocus />

Comment: @somenath-sinha  <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
            />
    <requestFocus />